# Automatically update the UICollectionView after an in-app purchase in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, in-app-purchase, updates

I followed this tutorial for in-app purchase: https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial
It works very good but I have a problem for updating the collectionview cell after purchase. I'm sure I'm close but I can't find the solution.

There is my problem: the app contains a collectionview where some item are grey when not purchased. And as soos as the purchase is completed with success, I want that all item become blue (the default color) and activated automatically . However that do not happened. I have to launch the app again to refresh the main view.

Here is my code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    isPremium = InAppProducts.store.isProductPurchased(InAppProducts.OrganicReactionFullApp)

    if !isPremium{
        InAppProducts.store.restorePurchases()
    }

    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.reload), for: .valueChanged)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.handlePurchaseNotification(_:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelper.IAPHelperPurchaseNotification),
                                           object: nil)

}    


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    reload()
}

func reload() {
    products = []        
    collectionView.reloadData()

    InAppProducts.store.requestProducts{success, products in
        if success {
            self.products = products!
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }

}

func handlePurchaseNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let productID = notification.object as? String else { return }

    for (index, product) in products.enumerated() {
        guard product.productIdentifier == productID else { continue }

        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)])
    }
}
```

and in UICollectionViewDataSource

```
  func collectionView(_ cellForItemAtcollectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // init cell code        
    if !isPremium && (indexPath.item == 5 || indexPath.item == 8 || indexPath.item == 9 || indexPath.item == 10) {
        cell.background.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }
    return cell
}
```

and UICollectionViewDelegate

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) {
// some delegate code
 switch indexPath.item {
    case 5, 8, 9:
        if !isPremium {
            if IAPHelper.canMakePayments(){
                InAppProducts.store.buyProduct(products[0])
               c
            }else {
                showAlert()
            }
        }else {
            popover.show(contentView: tableView, fromView: cell!)
        }
```

Of course, I didn't write all the code in UICollectionViewDelegate and datasource.

In place of 
    `DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        reload()
     }`

I tried without DispatchQueue.main.async, collectionview.reloadData, but same result.
I also try

```
` if success {
            isPremium = true
            self.products = products!
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }`
```

in reload() method, but all items were already blue (so activated) at the first launch.

Where is my fault? Help me please.
Thanks

Comment: It may be occurs because you give static color in cellForItemAtcollectionView ,  cell is reload and set color same.

Comment: the problem is not only the color, but item were not activated too. They still ask for purchase